# Failed to perform checkout on agent: Unable to delete conflicting workspace

Tags: teamcity

I am getting the following error when I my agent runs in TeamCity.

```
Failed to perform checkout on agent: Unable to delete conflicting workspace TeamCity-A5-fee2105439be4e36a53500ff137e8d32;edad1ed6-183e-4bb2-a41e-8b82fc3fa26f\alex. Please delete it manually
```

Where do I find and how do I delete these conflicting workspaces?

Comment: Have you checked your checkout dir location on the agent where this is being performed? Path would be something along the lines of *Teamcity\agentname\work*
Is this happening for all agents?

What type of build? Could you please provide more context?

Comment: @JeffGruenbaum forgive me, I'm super new to this app as I just inherited it from a previous team member. It is happening for all my agents. I will try to get back to you with more information and update my question.I will check into the areas you mentioned. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is talking about TFS/DevOps workspaces, not anything in your agent. I solved this by using tf.exe to delete workspaces from DevOps.

From the 'Developer Command Prompt for VS 2xxx' I ran these commands.

`tf workspaces /collection https://dev.azure.com/<your org> /owner:email@address.com`

The owner would be who your TeamCity VCS root is authenticating as which could be the account the TeamCity service account is running under, or whoever generated a DevOps PAT.

That will list out all the workspaces owned by that user, ACROSS ALL MACHINES. Find the workspaces that are attributed to a TeamCity build agent (comment on them may be "TeamCity checkout workspace") and run this command for each.

`tf workspace /collection https://dev.azure.com/<your org> /delete "<workspace name>;<owner name>"`

Note this is 'tf workspace', not 'workspaces'. For me the workspace was like "TeamCity-Af-(some GUID);email@address.com"